# Changing display color profiles easily

Tags: color

Is there a way to easily switch display color profiles, instead of going to System Preferences > Displays > Color > Display Profile?

It doesn't seem to be AppleScript-able. There used to be a menu-bar utility called [ProfileMenu](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26191/profilemenu), but it no longer works in macOS Sierra, and is no longer supported.

You can get the selected profile using AppleScript, but it's read-only, so you can't set it:

```
tell application "Image Events"
  get display profile of display 1
end tell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a little tool called [customdisplayprofiles](https://github.com/timsutton/customdisplayprofiles), which lets you switch profiles by running a command like `customdisplayprofiles set /path/to/profile.icc`. I put that into a shell script in `~/Library/Scripts/`, and now I can switch profiles from the menu bar again. You can find the .icc files in `/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/` and `~/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/`.